# Get orders by status Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Commerce using React and Firebase

I need to get all the orders with the status 'on-hold', so I did the following:

JS

```
    const ordersRef = firebase.database().ref('/orders');

    let orders = [];

    ordersRef.on('child_added', snap => {
      if (snap.val().status.state === 'on-hold') {
        orders = [
          {
            ...snap.val(),
            id: snap.key
          }, 
          ...orders
        ];
        this.setState({loading:false, orders: orders});
      }
    })
```

This is working, the only problem is that if there's no orders 'on-hold' the 'loading' state would never change.

The firebase db looks something like:

```
orders: {
  ...
  id: {
    ...
    status: {
      ...
      state: 'on-hold'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a query (to only get the orders that are on hold) and a `value` listener (to ensure you also get called when there are no orders that are on hold).

```
const ordersRef = firebase.database().ref('/orders');

let orders = [];

ordersRef.orderByChild("status/state").equalTo("on-hold").on('value', snapshot => {
  orders = [];
  snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
    orders.push({ ...snap.val(), id: snap.key });
  })

  this.setState({loading:false, orders: orders});
})
```